# Deleting all lvalue conversion operators

Tags: c++, type-conversion, operators, implicit-conversion

I want to avoid all lvalue conversions from a type to another type:

```
struct A
{};

struct T
{
    A a;
    operator A() { return a; }
    //operator A&() = delete; how to delete lvalue conversions to A?
};

void bar(A)
{}

void foo(const A&)
{}

void foo2(A&)
{}

int main()
{
    T t;

    bar(t); // fine
    foo(t); // should never convert to ref-to-const A
    foo2(t); // should never convert to ref-to A

    return 0;
}
```

Is this possible?
How and which conversion operators do I need to delete?

Example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/b6ss9a)

Comment: Why you overloaded operator if don't need it?

Comment: @LazarĐorđević He isn’t. Value conversion ≠ lvalue conversion.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you want to block conversions to a lvalue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might do

```
struct T
{
    A a;
    operator A() { return a; }
    
    template <typename T> operator const T&() = delete;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/67hx15)

Comment: Great, thx! Do you know why the templated version works and not deleting all non-templated operators?

Comment: It is related to overload resolution. (for `bar(A)`, both `T` -> `A` or `T` -> `const A&` are candidates). If there is a tie between 2 non-template methods, the call is ambiguous, if there is a tie between template and non-template, the non template wins.

Comment: Sorry to remove the accepted answer, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66157676/possible-bug-in-clang-or-gcc-because-of-deleted-templated-lvalue-conversion-oper

Comment: `c.a = t;` **is** a l-value conversion.so it doesn't invalidate my answer :), but probably break your underlying issue :/