# Possible bug in clang or gcc because of deleted templated lvalue conversion operator?

Tags: c++, gcc, type-conversion, operators, language-lawyer

This is a follow-up of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66153505/deleting-all-lvalue-conversion-operators) question.
I played with this code and used clang trunk and gcc trunk:

```
struct A
{   
};

struct T
{
    A a;
    operator A() { return a; }
    
    template <typename T> operator const T&() = delete;
};

struct C
{   
    A a;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    T t;

    c.a = t;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cG9K41)

Clang has nothing to complain, but gcc has:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:23:11: error: use of deleted function 'T::operator const T&() [with T = A]'
   23 |     c.a = t;
      |           ^
<source>:10:27: note: declared here
   10 |     template <typename T> operator const T&() = delete;
      |  

                     ^~~~~~~~
```

So, which compiler is right and which is wrong?

I would like to see gcc is wrong, but how can I overcome the error?

Comment: I added the `language-lawyer` tag and because i had to remove one, and discrepancy between compilers is not necessarily a bug in one I removed the `compiler-bug`.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I think it's very likely it's a compiler bug in either of them because it seems hard to believe anything regarding overload resolution is implementation-dependent (at least I can't think of one good reason why it should be).

Comment: Now I see... My bet is on gcc having a bug. You can simplify it further: https://godbolt.org/z/fo8WKs

Comment: But isn't this stuff very old? You would not even need a C++11 compiler?

Comment: @orlp I'd be fine with removing a different tag, but there can only be 5. I understood the question as asking for what the standard has to say about it, and whether it is a bug will follow from that. (btw compiler bug or not wasnt the point of my comment, I just wanted to leave a note for OP about what I changed and why, so they can roll-back, edit or do what they think fits best)

Comment: Why not `template <typename T> operator T() = delete;`?  Why the `const&`?

Comment: @Eljay: I need to delete all lvalue conversions, see the link to that question in the post. Other than that, it is NOK that stuff related to overloading is not handled equivalent IMHO.

Comment: Visual studio doesn't like it either: https://godbolt.org/z/sq811n, I'm not sure it makes sense to have a cast operator that returns a reference? It'd be difficult to implement correctly in a lot of cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Clang and GCC are wrong, but at least GCC stops compilation so it's marginally better.

`A` is a class type, and as such assigning to it passes through an `operator=` overload. You did not provide one, so the compiler provides two to the effect of

```
A& operator=(A const&) = default;
A& operator=(A&&) = default;
```

That reference argument is what needs to get initialized from `t` in the expression `c.a = t`. And for either `operator=`, the reference can be bound unambiguously.

> **[dcl.init.ref]**
>
> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.ref#5.1.2) A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of
> type “cv2 T2” as follows:
>
> - If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>
>   - [...]
>   - has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type), where T1 is not reference-related to T2, and can be converted to an lvalue of type
>     “cv3 T3”, where “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv3 T3” (this
>     conversion is selected by enumerating the applicable conversion
>     functions ([over.match.ref]) and choosing the best one through
>     overload resolution),
>
>   then the reference is bound ... to the lvalue result of the
>   conversion in the second case (or, in either case, to the appropriate
>   base class subobject of the object).
> - Otherwise, if the initializer expression
>
>   - [...]
>   - has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type), where T1 is not reference-related to T2, and can be converted to an rvalue or function
>     lvalue of type “cv3 T3”, where “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with
>     “cv3 T3” (see [over.match.ref]),
>
>   then ... the  result of the conversion in the second case is called
>   the converted initializer. If the converted initializer is a prvalue,
>   its type T4 is adjusted to type “cv1 T4” ([conv.qual]) and the
>   temporary materialization conversion ([conv.rval]) is applied. In any
>   case, the reference is bound to the resulting glvalue (or to an
>   appropriate base class subobject).

Where on the subject of building that candidate set for these two cases, the standard says

> **[over.match.ref]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.ref#1) Under the conditions specified in [dcl.init.ref], a reference can
> be bound directly to the result of applying a conversion function to
> an initializer expression. Overload resolution is used to select the
> conversion function to be invoked. Assuming that “reference to cv1 T”
> is the type of the reference being initialized, and “cv S” is the type
> of the initializer expression, with S a class type, the candidate
> functions are selected as follows:
>
> - The conversion functions of S and its base classes are considered. Those non-explicit conversion functions that are not hidden within S
>   and yield type “lvalue reference to cv2 T2” (when initializing an
>   lvalue reference or an rvalue reference to function) or “cv2 T2” or
>   “rvalue reference to cv2 T2” (when initializing an rvalue reference or
>   an lvalue reference to function), where “cv1 T” is
>   reference-compatible with “cv2 T2”, are candidate functions. For
>   direct-initialization, those explicit conversion functions that are
>   not hidden within S and yield type “lvalue reference to cv2 T2” (when
>   initializing an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference to function)
>   or “rvalue reference to cv2 T2” (when initializing an rvalue reference
>   or an lvalue reference to function), where T2 is the same type as T or
>   can be converted to type T with a qualification conversion, are also
>   candidate functions.

That bullet needs a bit of work to parse correctly, but it basically describes one of two disjoint cases that may apply here:

1. Initialization of an lvalue reference to T

   - The candidate functions are those that yield "lvalue reference to cv2 T2".
2. Initialization of an rvalue reference to T

   - The candidate functions are those that yield "cv2 T2" or "rvalue reference to cv2 T2".

For `operator=(A const&)` we are in case #1, and have a synthesized `operator A const&()` as the only candidate. For `operator=(A&&)` its case #2, and the non-template `operator A()` is the only candidate. Either way, we have an unambiguous implicit conversion sequence with a user-defined conversion that binds the reference parameter of either `operator=`.

But now neither `operator=` is a better viable function than the other according to the rules in [**[over.match.best]**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.best). And neither conversion is better according to the partial ordering in [**[over.ics.rank]**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank).

This means that the the program should be declared ill-formed on account of an ambiguous call to `operator=`. However, GCC and Clang both err (not MSVC though)<sup>1</sup>. Clang favors the `A&&` overload, while GCC goes for `A const&` and issues a diagnostic for the use of a deleted conversion function. But this isn't due to any standard mandated behavior. Ideally, they should both report the call to `operator=` is ambiguous.

---

<sup>1</sup> - [A comparison of different compiler behaviors, with a reduced example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:15,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:15,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:15,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:15,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%0Astruct+A%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+B+%7B%0A++++operator+A()+%7B+return+%7B%7D%3B+%7D%0A++++template%3Ctypename+T%3E%0A++++operator+T+const%26()+%3D+delete%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+foo(A+const%26)+%7B%7D%0Avoid+foo(A%26%26)+%7B%7D%0A%0Avoid+test()+%7B%0A++++B+b%3B%0A++++foo(b)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:51.45121801851598,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:clang1101,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27),(compilerId:g102,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_28_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2B17+/W4+/permissive-%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+viewer+(Editor+%231)+3/10%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.54878198148403,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this means that there is no way to prohibit lvalue conversions?

Comment: @Juergen - I could be wrong, but I don't believe there is. Not without affecting some pretty basic construct. Personally, I've yet to see a user-defined conversion to a reference that did not do something unexpected. I typically avoid conversion operators if it becomes too involved. As an aside, why would binding the result of the conversion to an lvalue reference be a problem?

Comment: Imagine a class which converts to std::optional<T>. When converting, I can't return a copy, since std::optional<T>& opt(myConverter) would loose the capability of updating the underlying value, isn't it?

Comment: Provided code prohibit l-value conversion... but assignment requires a lvalue...

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Strange, explicit cast also fails [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nbjG6h) (whereas implicit (from linked question) works)... Which are the difference?

Comment: @Jarod42 - The original involves copy initialization, and the cast is direct initialization. [dcl.init] may contain the reason, but I'm on mobile now, so checking is kinda hard.

Comment: @Juergen - A non-const lvalue reference won't bind if you return by value. And a const one won't allow modification. So what's the harm?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: see https://godbolt.org/z/35vMdh. The answer from Jarod42 in the other question is almost perfect for what I want. If only the copy-assignment would work like with the clang-bug :)

Comment: @Juergen - The bigger problem there is the dangling reference in `o`. I personally would question most if not all uses of a reference class member. But we digress.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: do you have a link why reference class members are 'bad'? I am really interested in this.

Comment: @Juergen - I updated the answer upon more reflection. Please take the time to review it. Regarding reference members. They are wonky. My biggest gripe is that they make initialization and assignment diverge. A copy/move constructor will initialize references to refer the same object as the reference in the source. But an assignment operator can't do that, since references cannot be re-seated, so it's [deleted by default](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.copy.assign#7.3). But if you implement it yourself, all you can do is assign to the referent. It's not intuitive on the whole.

Comment: @Juergen • rather than reference class member, there are other options, depending on the goal.  `public: std::string const& name;` that bound to `private: std::string name_;` as a read-only property getter, then `std::string name() const;` would be more idiomatic.  Avoid copying a large object but refer to it, (federated ownership) `std::shared_ptr<Large>` or (for non-owning) `std::weak_ptr<Large>` or even a non-owning `Large*` raw pointer (beware lifetime issues).